# How to convert sphinx real-time index to disk-based?

Tags: sphinx

I need to convert real-time index to disk-based without reindexing data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stop updating the RT index, its then disk based. (A RT index is a RAM chunk, and a series of Disk Chunks)

Use OPTIMIZE INDEX, to consolidate the chunks and flush the RAM chunk.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-optimize-index

(in theory you could take the RT files - after the optimize and rename them to fit the pattern of a disk index - with a suitable config for it in the config file. But no idea if will work in practice)